# Не могу в Ubuntu 22.04 зайти в phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

На Ubuntu 22.04 установлен LAMP и phpMyAdmin (вроде, как установлен). Сначала при установке возникали ошибки, снес phpMyAdmin, переустановил с логином и паролем root. Кажется, все встало. Но не могу через браузер зайти на phpMyAdmin.

Пробовал localhost/phpmyadmin, http://localhost/phpmyadmin, 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin - результат один Not found. Подскажите, кто знает, в чем проблема и как ее решить?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Когда кажется - креститься надо. Что мешает проверить, есть ли по пути установки сам phpmyAdmin?

Comment: Если подскажете как, я обязательно проверю. я не линксоид, не знаю, как это сделать

Comment: Ну, не имея доступа к вашей системе, трудно искать все причины - а их может быть сотня. Гляньте тут https://askubuntu.com/a/381372 - возможно, поможет. Чтобы не переписывать все советы.

Comment: спасибо, перепробовал все оттуда, не работает. но теперь вместо ошибки 404 просто пустая страница открывается. phpmyadmin установился в var/www/html